# How to do Excel data validation on sum of multiple cells including empty cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I need to validate the sum of several cells in a row at Excel.

For example:
I have cells F3 to R3.
I want to check if the sum from F3 to R3 is equal to 1.
F3 to R3 data:
[image: F3 to R3 data]

I have used the formula below in data validation to ensure the sum is always equal to 1.

```
=SUM($F$3:$R$3) = 1
```

Here is the screenshot of my data validation settings:
Data validation settings:
[image: Data validation settings]

It works well when I change the value along F3 to R3.

However, when I remove the value in F3 (F3 is an empty cell), the data validation fails to work. Here is the screenshot: Empty cells in F3:
[image: Empty cells in F3]

Question:

1. Which formula should I use in Data Validation in Excel so Excel always validate the sum of all the cells (including empty cells) equal to one?

Comment: un-check the ignore blank option.

Comment: Nothing is wrong as such, Excel is justifying the Formula in fact. Suppose F3 to R3 are blank and you have applied the Data Validation using =Sum($F$3:$R$3)=1, means excel will not allow to enter more that 1 in any of the Cells. If you try to write any value after 1 is entered any where in the said data range, you will be prompted.

Comment: Situation 2,, if all the cell are filled with any value 1 or any,, and you apply Validation, then after if you delete any of the cells and write any value even 1, will be prompted. The reason is Sum($F$3:$R$3)=1 means ONLY 1 in any of the cells in the said data range.